# Read JSON array with empty or blank fields using jackson

Tags: java, arrays, json, jackson

I am using [Jackson](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/) to parse a jsonString that looks like this:

```
{
  "key": "Flowers",
  "colorized": true,
  "values": [
    [1472428800000,  , "#aaaaaa", "", ""], //empty or blank field
    [1472515200000,  , "#bbbbbb", "", ""], //empty or blank field
    [1472601600000,  , "#cccccc", "", ""], //empty or blank field
    [1472688000000, 1, "#dddddd", "", ""], //field not empty or blank anymore
    [1472774400000, 2, "#eeeeee", "", ""],
    [1472860800000, 3, "#ffffff", "", ""],
    [1472947200000, 4, "#aaaaaa", "", ""]
  ]
}
```

When I use `JsonNode jsonNode = mapper.readTree(jsonString)` Jackson throws an Exception:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: 
Unexpected character (',' (code 44)): 
expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
```

It seems to me that it is because of the empty or blank field. Searching the web yielded only solutions for fields that are `null, [] or {}` but not completely blank.

**Question:** How can I achieve that Jackson parses the string and treats those empty fields as `""` or `null`?

**EDIT1:**

I have used

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20140107</version>
</dependency>
```

in the past and calling `new JSONObject(jsonString)` with that library on the jsonString worked just fine. I want to focus on Jackson and get rid of that dependency because of the performance. I am sure Jackson is able to handle it as well somehow.

Comment: You cannot, as this is not valid JSON.  You will need to go back to whomever or whatever is creating the JSON and have that fixed.

Comment: @Joe C I edited my answer. Other JSON libraries seem to be able to handle it just fine.

Comment: According to [http://json.org/](http://json.org/), arrays are made of values and a string must be one of string / number / object / array / true / false / null.  [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) is a handy online JSON parser - just paste your sample there (remove the comments) and try to validate it. It is not valid JSON.Other libs may parse it and you may get by on that but if those libs decide to clean up their act in the future then you may have an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the desired behaviour with this configuration:

```
mapper.enable(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_MISSING_VALUES);
```

According to [Jackson docs](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-core/wiki/JsonParser-Features):

> ALLOW_MISSING_VALUES
>   Feature allows the support for "missing" values
>   in a JSON array: missing value meaning sequence of two commas, without
>   value in-between but only optional white space

The missing values appear as `null` inside `JsonNode`

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!